# Is there a way to put multiple inline elements at different specific positions within one line in HTML?

Tags: html, css, position

Sorry if my question is unclear. I mean let's say I want to put three words in a line but one at the leftmost, one at the center, and the last one is at the right most. Besides putting a lot of spaces between them(which is such an unprofessional and funny way to do), is there any way to specify the positions?

My first thought is like:

```html
<p>
     <span style="text-align: left">Left</span>
     <span style="text-align: center">Center</span>
     <span style="text-align: right">Right</span>
</p>
```

And apparently it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Comment: You say "inline elements", but do they have to be inline as in display: inline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you mean like this?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p class="flex">
    <span>Left</span>
    <span>Center</span>
    <span>Right</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That's very easy and direct and satisfy my needs thanks a lot k185! :D

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. Some that haven't been mentioned so far are floating the first span to the left and the last one to the right.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

p > span:first-child {
  float: left;
}

p > span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span>Center</span>
  <span>Right</span>
</p>
```

If the spans all consist of only one word each, you can use text-align and text-align-last.
If they do consist of multiple words, you also may have to change them to display:inline-block to avoid stretching the spaces inside them.

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span>Center</span>
  <span>Right</span>
</p>
```

Changing the p to a table will work too, but is not recommended.

```css
p {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

p > span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

p > span:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

p > span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span>Center</span>
  <span>Right</span>
</p>
```

A newer method is using `display:grid`. This is so new, in fact, that depending on the version of the browser you're using, you'll need to enable this in the browser's advanced settings. See the footnotes to MDN's [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid#Browser_compatibility) table.

```css
p {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3];
  grid-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
}

p>span {
  display: block;
}

p>span:nth-child(2) {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

p>span:last-child {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span>Center</span>
  <span>Right</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Lister that's a very comprehensive and helpful answer to solve this problem! Learned all of them from you! :D

Answer (score 2):

you can try using

```
<p> 
<span id="left">Left</span> 
<span id="center">Center</span> 
<span id="right">Right</span> 
</p> 

<style>
 #left{ float:left; }
 #center{ padding-left:50px;}//you can adjust the space you want(exp:70px or more) 
 #right{ float:right; } </style>
```

or

```
<style>
 #left{ float:left; }
 #center{ padding-left:50px;}//you can adjust the space you want(exp:70px or more) 
 #right{ padding-left:50px; } </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it all in a div and style it like:

```
div {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Have you tested? And why should it be put in a div?

Comment: @MrLister because text align must be assigned to parent element and that's why <span style="text-aligh: left"> doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide a snippet?